# EF Core: Dealing with nullable in PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am changing my server from SQL Server to PostgreSQL now. I have difficulties on dealing with nullable value. I have so many models with nullable and many logics.

```
public class POS_OwnerAccount
{
    [Key]
    [IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    [IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public string ForgetPasswordHash { get; set; }
    public int? ConfirmationToken { get; set; } = null;

    public bool IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; } = false;

    public string ApiLoginHash { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ApiLoginHashExpiration { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? LastEmailConfirmationSent { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastEmailForgotPasswordSent { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public ICollection<POS_Store> Stores { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeactivated { get; set; } = false;
}
```

If I try to insert the data, it throws this error:

> 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Any of these properties give me this error:

```
public string Hash {get;set;}
public int? ConfirmationToken {get;set;}
public DateTimeOffset? 
public ICollection<POS_Store> Stores {get;set;}
```

All of the properties above are set to `NULL` and this creates problem.

How can I deal with this?

---

### EF CORE CREATION SCHEMA

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "OwnerAccounts",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Password = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Hash = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                ForgetPasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                ConfirmationToken = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true),
                IsEmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "boolean", nullable: false),
                ApiLoginHash = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                ApiLoginHashExpiration = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: true),
                LastEmailConfirmationSent = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: true),
                LastEmailForgotPasswordSent = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: true),
                DateCreated = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false),
                IsDeactivated = table.Column<bool>(type: "boolean", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_OwnerAccounts", x => x.ID);
            });
```

Comment: Show us the schema for the table.

Comment: PostgreSQL some times gives me the same error from a java project, where the kind of debug dumps I log for it show me there is no string with a zero character or a null string when it happens. I think the problem is either in their database drivers or even in the database itself.

Comment: For me nullables work well, but I never use `type: "text"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my `Password` which gives me the error. My password is encrypted and it has `0x00` character in it. So I have to replace the `0x00` before saving to the database.